# A shape for a button (AndroidStudio)

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-studio, button, shapes

Trying to do a simple thing, to apply a shape for a button. But! From my simple shape xml only the corner tag works, but the stroke tag isn't applied for my button.

**button_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

**button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/genres_or_languages_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Something"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape">
</Button>
```

Everything should be so easy that I don't even know what can be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the button inside any layout like constraint layout
2. Use backgroundTint instead of background.
3. Change the color from button_shape.xml
4. Use dp instead of dip

**You can also use appcompat button**
*If you use appcompat button use only background not backgroundTint*